# Apache tiles converts open tag and close tag with no content to an empty tag

Tags: java, apache-tiles

Apache tiles converts open tag and close tag with no content to an empty tag.

For example `<script src="some.js"></script>` will be written as `<script src="some.js"/>`, which breaks my HTML.

How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: How does it break? as this is just as valid

Comment: Content after not endted script tag is not shown.

Comment: @Mark: It breaks because browsers don't recognise self-closed script tags, they *have* to be in the form `<script></script>`. I don't why this is, it just is.

Comment: Lots of information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 2):

Solution below works. This is how [Spring Roo](https://github.com/krimple/spring-roo-in-action-examples/blob/master/chapter-01-intro/pizzashop-layered/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx) work-around this problem.

```
<script src="some.js"><!----></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really "break your HTML"? Did you check with a validator, like [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/)? You are describing perfectly valid XML. To which DTD should your HTML conform? Personally, I would aim for XHTML, where this is not a problem.

**Edit**: Is your server delivering `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`? It seems some browser will not be too happy with XHTML delivered as text/html.

Comment: This is not a validation issue. Page displays incorrect in my browser, because some HTML tags required to be ended, such as textarea or script.

Comment: Try this HTML code with not ended script tag. The body wouldn't be displayed.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js" />

<title>Forum</title>

</head>

<body>
Some content
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some content in between the script start and end tags, enough to stop Tiles from collapsing it down.  Try some white space, or a line break, or even a `&nbsp;`. If Tiles keeps doing it, you need to introduce some content in there that it won't collapse, perhaps a javascript comment?

Comment: Comment doesn't work, but &nbsp; or some content works. But what about textarea tag, if I don't whant any content in it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't suppose this works?

```
<script src="some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="some.js" type="text/javascript">&nbsp;</script>
```

Not too sure the above would even solve the validation issue, even if it did work